# Will this get Search Engines to index my content?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, database

I have a classifieds website...

The classifieds are displayed in a dynamic php page.

For instance, if one searches for "**bmw m3**" in the form (which is in **index.html**) and submits, then a php page will appear showing results.

The php page called **results.php**, connects to **mysql** databases and fetches the information, and puts them in a table, and then outputs the table using a simple echo command.

```
  <body>
     echo $table;
  </body>
```

The classifieds shown in the table above, are all just "**headlines**", so when clicking one classified to view all details, then another php page opens called **ad.php**.

Here I fetch the **ad_id** and then fetch all details from **MySql**, and show to the users.

Now, if somebody doesn't like filling out forms (for example google crawlers, or also users), I have all categories on my site at the bottom of **index.html**. Users may click these and then the **results.php** page appears, showing all results in that category.

Offcourse I also have a **sitemap** which consists of all classifieds, and is dynamic.

My problem is, so far, none of my classifieds have been indexed.

My question is, is a **sitemap.xml** with all classifieds in it, as well as a link to the **results.php** page for each category enough for Search Engines to index the classifieds?

What else do I need to do?

FYI: I use **mod rewrite** to rewrite urls, so in this case I have a rule which makes the original link to details of a classified:

```
   www.domain.com/ad.php?ad_id=bmw_m3_249244
```

INTO:

```
   www.domain.com/ads/bmw_m3_249244
```

And it is the rewritten URL I have in my sitemap.

Thanks

Comment: Probably just need to wait. Consider adding `<meta>` tags to help Google along, though. Also, you can register as a webmaster with Google and submit a site to them to speed up the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you submitted your sitemap.xml to the search engines? or specified it in the robots.txt?

Link below explains.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described , Google shouldnt have any problem indexing your pages. There are maybe other things involved. For instance if the links to the category pages and classified pages are done with Javascript, google will not index that. How long have your pages been online? Does the main page show up in google search?